# Issue With Jboss Session Management

Tags: java, jboss

I am having 2 applications deployed in Jboss, I want both of them to share the session between them bascially use the same JSESSIONID. I am able to achieve this by adding the below line in the web.xml of both the applications.

```
     <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <path>/</path>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

But I dont want to add it in my web.xml as I may have many applications deployed and everybody should have this in their web.xml. I was searching for a way to do it in my Jboss itself and find some properties like below.

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR" value="false"/>
</system-properties>
```

or

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.SESSION_ID_CHECK" value="false"/>
</system-properties>
```

But none of this is working. Please let me know if there is any way to accomplish it. I am using Jboss as 7.1.1.Final.

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell this isn't possible with JBoss 7.1. The source for the embedded tomcat (7.0) is always looking at: 1.context config, 2.cookie name in web.xml, 3. default.

If I had to dig into this further, I would look at doing a re-write at your load balancer. If you are using something like apache with mod_proxy you could use ProxyPassReverseCookiePath to change the cookies after they come from JBoss.

Comment: we are not using a load balancer.